# SQLite and Linq error: No such table

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, dblinq

I have created a Linq and SQLite app in C#/winform with DBLinq using these two commands:

```
DbMetal /provider:Sqlite /conn "Data Source=path\to\database.s3db" /dbml:path\to\Database.dbml
```

and:

```
DbMetal /code:path\to\DatabaseContext.cs path\to\Database.dbml
```

To get a connection to database:

```
string dataSource = @"Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "database.s3db";
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dataSource);
Main db = new Main(connection, new SqliteVendor());
```

And to query database:

```
var user = db.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
```

Running this line of code, I get `No shuch table` Exception:

```
no such table: main.USER
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled HResult=-2147467259 Message=SQLite error
no such table: main.USER
Source=System.Data.SQLite 
ErrorCode=-2147467259
StackTrace:
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()        
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
    at DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.Implementation.QueryRunner.Select[T](SelectQuery selectQuery)
    at DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.Implementation.QueryRunner.SelectSingle[S](SelectQuery selectQuery, Boolean allowDefault)
    at DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.Implementation.QueryRunner.SelectScalar[S](SelectQuery selectQuery)
    at DbLinq.Data.Linq.Implementation.QueryProvider`1.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
    at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
...
```

Database file exists and I have the table.
Any Idea?

Comment: Could the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory be other than expected? I recommend dumping/inspecting the actual connection string. Remember that SQLite will usually happily create a *new* database if needed.

Comment: I checked the URL and database at that URL. Everything is OK. Problem is somewhere else...

Comment: In the file *specified in the connection string* is opened with the sqlite3 CLI, what happens when running `select * from main.USER`?

Comment: I am using SQLite Browser. I run query and get result without any problem.

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas :( Good luck.

Comment: You were right! I missed one level in my file path! sorry!

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out! Consider posting a self-answer (explaining the problem and how it was verified/solved) :D